# How create standalone application from wsdl?

Tags: java, service, wsdl

I have wsdl file from which I have generated by web services of eclipse 2 interfaces and 2 classes - locator and stub. It all run as web application. But I need to create standalone application. How it can be done?

Comment: What do you mean by stand alone application ?

Comment: that can be run independently - without e.g. tomcat, like executable. E.g. java -jar app.jar .....